# Add a hash to an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I've currently got this hash:

```
{:residential=>"false"}
```

But I need to make it an item of an array:

```
[{:residential=>"false"}]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Any ruby codes that you have tried so far?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've written?

Comment: @Benoit: I'm working with an external API that doesn't format their data consistently, so needing to force it.

Comment: @Shpigford Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, I'll rephrase: what's wrong with `my_hash = [my_hash]`? Is the hash you're trying to wrap nested?

Comment: `{:residential=>"false"}` isn't an array, it's a hash.

Comment: @knut: Doh. Typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
my_array = []
my_array << {:residential => "false"}
=> [{:residential=>"false"}]
```

Comment: Any idea how you can save `my_array` to an active record column and retrieve it afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

The code you've already written should be just fine.

```
>> x = [{:residental=>"false"}, {:residental=>"true"}]                  
=> [{:residental=>"false"}, {:residental=>"true"}]                      
>> x[0][:residental]                                                    
=> "false"
```